# Future timestamps formatted as 1. January 1970 with PHP date()

Tags: php, date, timestamp, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've been reading for hours and can't figure this out: I format a date (strtotime) from datepicker for DB use. then when i display it again i make it "readable" with date(). this works fine in the past, but future dates only work in the current month, as soon as i try the 1st of the next month or further into the future, strtotime() produces an empty string as it seems.

this is the code:

```
$('#datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker({

        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        dateFormat:'d. MM yy'

        });
    });



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
        <input name="date" type="text" id="datepicker">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <br><br>

    <?php

        $sent_date = $_POST['date']??"30. Oktober 2018";
        $formatted_date = strtotime($sent_date);
        $readable_date = date("l, j. F Y", $formatted_date);

        echo "formatted date: " . $formatted_date . "<br><br>";
        echo "readable date: " . $readable_date;

    ?>
```

Comment: What are you passing to `date()`? My guess would be `$formatted_date` is not a timestamp.

Comment: `30. Oktober 2018` is not a valid date format for `strtotime()` to parse

Comment: @miken32 as an example, this is what i'm passing to date(): 1541804400 when i pick 10. November 2018 in datepicker. the $readable_date then echoes as "Saturday, 10. November 2018"

Comment: Ok but what are you passing when it _doesn't_ work. We're interested in the failure condition here.

Comment: @JohnConde that's just a placeholder, could be an empty string as well, as i choose the date from datepicker, where it is submitted as e.g. date: 1. Oktober 2018 - and this does work as long as date is from the current month or older, but not in the future starting from the 1st of next month

Comment: @miken32 when it doesn't work, the $formatted_date echoes nothing, so i assume it's an empty string

Comment: Don't assume. Try using `var_dump()` instead of echo.

Comment: this is super weird, without me changing anything it worked 3 times, now back to not working... var_dump says: bool(false)

Comment: Protip: Don't let users enter dates as free-form text fields, and don't rely on "magic" like `strtotime()` to try and parse whatever random nonsense a user feels like entering that day. Give them separate year/month/day fields, or _rigidly_ enforce a single well-defined string format.